# Hibernate Tools Eclipse Classpath

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, classpath, hibernate-tools

How do I set the classpath in eclipse which is used by Hibernate Tools?

I have tried right-clicking on my project, going to properties, then Java Build Path, then the Libraries tab, and adding the appropriate JARs. However, Hibernate Tools still gives a classNotFound even after I added the JAR using the above process.

Answer (score 0):

The Classpath is set in the "Hibernate Console Configuration" dialog box. It appears to be separate from the standard eclipse classpath.